# Enable a p:tab in a p:tabView already disabled without updating all form (primefaces)

Tags: javascript, primefaces

How to update a tab inside a tabView which is already disabled.

I've tried to update only the header by the class name `(.ui-tabs-nav)`, but nothing happens. I've also sought to add a div between the `tabView` and `Tab` to update it by id or use simply a style, but JSF does not render this one.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to doing that directly using JavaScript, by changing the class value.

When JSF generate the HTML code, it fills every class tag in those tabs by values. If we observe an enabled tab we notice that the class contains  `ui-state-default ui-corner-top` and a disabled class contains `ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-state-disabled`

to select the desired tab i used this expression

```
$('ul.ui-tabs-nav li:eq(n)')
```

and to change the class value

```
1- $('ul.ui-tabs-nav li:eq(n)').attr('class', 'ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-state-disabled');  

2- $('ul.ui-tabs-nav li:eq(n)').attr('class', 'ui-state-default ui-corner-top');
```

Another alternative is to use :

`widgetVar` tag inside the primefaces tabView with `PF('tabView').enable(n)` and `PF('tabView').disable(n)`

n is the tab Rank starting from 0